# Standard Error of the Regression Formula for General Time-Series Confidence Intervals

Tags: time-series, forecasting, standard-error

Let's say that I use a forecasting model to product a single-point forecast. The table below represents the outcomes on the previous 4 years:

| Year | Y | Prediction | Error | Error ^ 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Year 1 | 11 | 14 | -3 | 9 |
| Year 2 | 12 | 10 | 2 | 4 |
| Year 3 | 9 | 10 | -1 | 1 |
| Year 4 | 16 | 14 | 2 | 4 |

If I want to use this model to predict what the value will be in `Year 5` (regardless of model type), is it appropriate to use the Standard Error of the Regression formula*1.96 to create a +/-95% confidence interval around the `Year 5` prediction?

i.e.,: `SQRT(SUM(Error^2)/(Observation Count - 2)) * 1.96` or written in Python:

```
import numpy as np

errors = [-3, 2, -1, 2]
errors_squared = [x**2 for x in errors]
std_err_of_regr = np.sqrt(sum(errors_squared)/(len(errors)-2))
ci_95 = std_err_of_regr*1.96

print(ci_95)
5.88
```

Comment: after some more research, the Standard Error of the Regression subtracts 2 from `n` in the denominator because of needing to account for the intercept and the slope in a Regression Model. I'm thinking that my approach should be more aligned with a straight-forward Standard Error (i.e., Standard Deviation of a Sample), where I subtract 1 from `n`.

Comment: I don't think you can use standard error as a legit CI for your forecast. The CI you calculated is associated with in sample data whereas for out of sample or future you expect higher uncertainty. I am Bayesian and in Bayesian approach the reasonable CI is naturally estimated, I am not sure about how to do it in frequentist approach you are taking. Maybe try bootstrapping.